# Lines from a file as variables

Tags: php, loops, output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" /> 
        <title>squared.php</title>
        <link href="/library/skin/tool_base.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <link href="/library/skin/durham/tool.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/library/js/headscripts.js"></script>
        <style>body { padding: 5px !important; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Squared</title>
            <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css">
        <h1> Squared  </h1>
    </head>
    <?php
    //Save the three values from the file
    $beginningNum = $_POST['beginningNum'];
    $endingNum = $_POST['endingNum'];
    $incrementer = $_POST['incrementer'];

    //Open the file and read the numbers
    $dataFilePointer = fopen("output.txt", "r");

    $beginningNum = fgets($dataFilePointer);
    $endingNum = fgets($dataFilePointer);
    $incrementer = fgets($dataFilePointer);


    fclose($dataFilePointer);

    // Loop through beginning with beginningNum until you get to endingNum and increment by incrementer
    // The first statement says "Start x at the entered beginningNum
    // The second statement says "Loop until $x gets to the endingNum value
    // The third statement says "Increment $x by the incrementer after every loop (also known as counter)
    // Check to make sure each value is a numeric then do the for loop, if not - print an error message
    if (is_numeric($beginningNum) and is_numeric($endingNum) and is_numeric($incrementer)) {
        for ($x = $beginningNum; $x <= $endingNum; $x += $incrementer) {

            //Square $x for every increment of it using pow
            $squaredNum = pow($x, 2);

            // Print $squaredNum to the user
            print("<p> The Final Results are $squaredNum.</p>");
        }
    } else {
        print("<p>Error.</p>");
        print("<a href=\"squared.html\">Return to Form.</a>");
    }
    ?>
```

This is what I have so far. I want to write a `squared.php` file that receives a filename from `squared.html`. It should read three values from that file:

1. The first line in the file will contain the starting value
2. The second line in the file will contain the ending value
3. The third line in the file will contain the value by which the counter is updated (often increments, but not always)

** Wait for instruction on Wednesday about this:

```
     Read these 3 values, and confirm that they are numeric values using the `php` function `is_numeric()`.

     If not, display an error message and offer the user a link to return to the `HTML`.
```

If it is valid input, your code should contain the following logic:

Use a for loop that will use the start, ending, and update values to display the those values squared.

For example, if a user enters: (I will test your code with other values)

Start Value: 5

End Value: 20

Increment: 5

Your results should be:

5 squared is 25

10 squared is 100

15 squared is 225

20 squared is 400

Comment: You are reading from `$_POST` but then overwriting the values from the file. You probably need to read values from the file first and then do something like `if (isset($_POST['beginningNum'])) { $beginningNum = $_POST['beginningNum']; }`

Comment: Interesting. So how would I read from the file first?

Comment: Just move the 3 lines that do the `fgets` before the 3 lines that use the `$_POST` then replace the 3 lines that use the `$_POST` with the `isset` lines (or probably better `if (!empty($_POST['beginninNum']) { .. }`

Comment: Ok, because everytime I try to run it, the same errors keep showing up and it is the POST lines. Ok cool, lets see what happens.

Comment: Should we not **wait till wednesday** to give an answer then

Comment: Ok, now it is saying the txt file doesnt exist and that there are errors with the lines involving the fgets and the fclose line. You'll have to forgive me, I am a new college student getting my feet wet with php.

Comment: DOCTYPE does not belong inside the body tag

Comment: Ignore the "wait until Wednesday" part. I shouldve took that out, that was taken care of last wednesday.

Comment: You do not have a `<form>` so how are you expecting to fill the `$_POST` array

Comment: First rule of homework, Read and understand the question

Comment: The form is in my html program for this.